# ¿Cómo puedo comparar archivos ascii específicos de dos rutas distintas en python?

Tags: python-2.7, diccionarios, rutas, comparaciones, ascii

Se me ha pedido como ejercicio comparar 5 archivos tipo ascii pero de diferentes rutas. El problema es que los archivos tienen nombres distintos (en una carpeta se llaman de un modo y en la otra de otra forma pero el contenido es el mismo).
Las acciones deben de realizarse mediante botones.
Logré que se compararán pero:
1.Eligiendo las rutas en "orden", si se eligen al revés ya no funciona
2. Se hace mediante muchos for
La idea es que no haga un ciclo for por cada tupla de archivo, si no que salga en una sola corrida. Intenté hacerlo mediante diccionarios pero no me sale.
3.Si los archivos son distintos te dice que archivo y que línea es distinta y si no, solo debe de imprimir "IDENTICAL"
Soy principiante en python y agradecería mucho si me dieran una solución.
Anexo mi código

```
def openSelectFile1():
    
    global file_path
    
    root = Tkinter.Tk() #close the window by tkinter
    root.withdraw() #close
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory() #open the file explorer and save the selection in the variable


def openSelectFile2():
    
    global file_path2
    
    root = Tkinter.Tk() #close the window by tkinter
    root.withdraw() #close
    file_path2 = tkFileDialog.askdirectory() #open the file explorer and save the selection in the variable
    

def compareBothFiles():   

    #dic={1:['/CORE0.asc', '/CORE1.asc', '/EEPROM_EXT.asc', '/ETS.asc', '/FBL.asc']} `nombres de archivos ascii de la primera ruta`
    #dic2={2:['/CHR_ORC_C0_Appl_opt.asc', '/CHR_ORC_C1_opt.asc', '/CHR_ORC_ETS_opt.asc', '/CHR_ORC_FBL_Appl_opt.asc', '/EEPROM_Ext_EMPTY.asc']} `nombres de archivos ascii de la segunda ruta`


    #values= dic.values()
    #values2= dic2.values()
    #print(values)
    
    #f1 = open(file_path+values)
    #f2 = open(file_path2+values2)

       
    f1 = open(file_path+'/CORE0.asc')
    f2 = open(file_path2+'/CHR_ORC_C0_Appl_opt.asc')
    
    i=0
    for line1 in f1:
        i += 1
        for line2 in f2:
                if line1 != line2:
                    print("Line:", i, "= DIFFERENT")
                    print("difference in: ", '/CORE0.s37')
                    print("difference in: ", '/CHR_ORC_Appl_opt.s37')
                else:
                    print(" ")
                break 
                

           
    f1 = open(file_path+'/CORE1.asc')
    f2 = open(file_path2+'/CHR_ORC_C1_opt.asc')
 
    i=0
    for line1 in f1:
        i += 1
        for line2 in f2:
                if line1 != line2:
                    print("Line:", i, "= DIFFERENT")
                    print("difference in: ",'/CORE1.asc')
                    print("difference in: ",'/CHR_ORC_C1_opt.asc')
                else:
                    print(" ")
                break 
            
           
    f1 = open(file_path+'/EEPROM_EXT.asc')
    f2 = open(file_path2+'/EEPROM_Ext_EMPTY.asc')
 
    i=0
    for line1 in f1:
        i += 1
        for line2 in f2:
                if line1 != line2:
                    print("Line:", i, "= DIFFERENT")
                    print("difference in: ",'/EEPROM_EXT.asc')
                    print("difference in: ",'/EEPROM_Ext_EMPTY.asc')
                else:
                    print(" ")
                break 

           
    f1 = open(file_path+'/ETS.asc')
    f2 = open(file_path2+'/CHR_ORC_ETS_opt.asc')
 
    i=0
    for line1 in f1:
        i += 1
        for line2 in f2:
                if line1 != line2:
                    print("Line:", i, "= DIFFERENT")
                    print("difference in: ",'/ETS.asc')
                    print("difference in: ",'/CHR_ORC_ETS_opt.asc')
                else:
                    print(" ")
                break 

          
    f1 = open(file_path+'/FBL.asc')
    f2 = open(file_path2+'/CHR_ORC_FBL_Appl_opt.asc')
 
    i=0
    for line1 in f1:
        i += 1
        for line2 in f2:
                if line1 == line2:
                    print('')
                else:
                    print("Line ", i, ": DIFFERENT")
        
                    print("difference:", '/FBL.asc')
                    print("difference:", '/CHR_ORC_FBL_Appl_opt.asc')
                break

    
def quit():
    root.destroy()



if __name__ =='__main__':   
    root = Tk()
    
    Label(root, text="COMPARE").pack(side=TOP)
    compareFrame = LabelFrame(root, text = "Selection your files to compare", padx=5, pady=5)
    compareFrame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)  
    Button(root, text="Compare", padx=30, pady=5, command=compareBothFiles).pack()
    Label(root, text="").pack()
    
    Button(compareFrame, text="File 1", padx=70, pady=5,  command=openSelectFile1).grid(row=1, column=1)
    Button(compareFrame, text="File 2", padx=70, pady=5, command=openSelectFile2).grid(row=2, column=1)
    Label(root, text="").pack()
    
    Button(root, text="close",bg= "lightgray", padx=15, pady=5,  command=quit).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    
    
    root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    root.title("HexView and Compare")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Las funciones pueden recibir parámetros. De ese modo, una misma función te sirva para comparar cualquier par de archivos. `compareBothFiles()` debería recibir parámetros f1 y f2, y así no tendrías que repetir el mismo código una y otra vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Python, como en cualquier otro lenguaje, es posible pasar *parámetros* a una función para que opere sobre una amplia variedad de valores. Pasar parámetros vía variables globales es un profundo error.

En particular, podemos escribir una función que compare dos archivos arbitrarios y nos diga si son iguales o distintos.

Esta función no depende de variables globales ni nada externo; está totalmente autocontenida; sólo tienes que proporcionar los nombres de los archivos.

Esta función recibirá los nombres de los archivos (con el path completo) y devolverá `True` o `False` según sean iguales o distintos:

```
def comparar(archivo1: str, archivo2: str) -> bool:
    with open(archivo1, "r") as arch1:
        with open(archivo2, "r") as arch2:
            while True:
                linea1 = arch1.readline()
                linea2 = arch2.readline()
                if linea2 != linea1:
                    return False
                if linea1 == '':
                    break
            
    return True
```

El procedimiento es simple: se abren los archivos y se lee una línea de cada uno y se comparan. Si son distintas, se retorna `False`. Si son iguales, se sigue con el siguiente par, excepto que hayamos llegado al final del archivo. Eso se detecta porque la línea leida tiene largo cero.

#### Demo

*Archivo leer.txt*

```
1,2,3,4,6
21,611,31,66,1
3,63,13,7,8,12,1
```

*Archivo leer2.txt*

```
1,2,3,4,6
21,611,31,66,1
3,63,13,7,8,12,1
ultima
```

*Código*

```
#   Comparemos un archivo contra si mismo.
iguales = comparar("leer.txt", "leer.txt")
print(iguales)

#   Comparamos dos archivos distintos.
iguales = comparar("leer.txt", "leer2.txt")
print(iguales)

#   La comparación funciona en cualquier orden
iguales = comparar("leer.txt", "leer2.txt")
print(iguales)
```

produce:

```
True
False
False

Process finished with exit code 0
```